# DB2 v.10.1 RDF data deletion

Tags: db2, rdf, sparql, jena

Have anybody tried to remove data(triples) from the DB2 RDF simple store(Windows)? (INSERT works fine)

SPARQL DELETE statament:

```
DELETE { ?document ?property ?value} WHERE{ ?document <http://example.com#begin> 
?begin . 
FILTER(?begin > 200) ?document ?property ?value }
```

I've got the following exception:

```
com.ibm.rdf.store.exception.RdfStoreException: DB255006E ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001. SQLSTATE: 08001.
 at  
com.ibm.rdf.store.internal.jena.impl.update.SingleTripleOperations.removeQuad(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.rdf.store.internal.jena.impl.update.AbstractTripleOperation.removeQuad(Unknown Source)
.....
```

db2diag.log:

```
RETCODE : ZRC=0x87120007=-2028863481=SQLR_SEVERE_PGM_ERROR
"Severe programming error"
DIA8516C A severe internal processing error has occurred.
```

My Java code:

```
String queryString = "delete ...";
Dataset ds = RdfStoreFactory.connectDataset(storeP, conn);
GraphStore graphStore = GraphStoreFactory.create(ds) ;
UpdateAction.parseExecute(queryString, graphStore); // exception

 //UpdateAction.parseExecute("DROP ALL", graphStore); // works fine
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved by adding

```
    prop.setProperty("enableExtendedIndicators", "2");
```

to the DB2 connection.

Comment: @gmivsv Out of interest why is that necessary and how did you find it out?  Adding this to your answer will allow others with the same/similar problems to solve their problems more easily in the future

Comment: I do not know why this is necessary but it works. I tried the working example from [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/tutorials/dm-1205rdfdb210/section3.html) and compared with my code.

Comment: Reply from the author of the article: 
one of the delete statements we use has a problem between the JDBC driver and DB2 server if this is not turned off. There is a defect already opened with the respective IBM teams. 
Mario